# Infix to Postfix convertion

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

what is the correct way of writing the following infix expression in postfix form?

1. $(A - C > T)  $ OR $(G $ x $H \le B) $ AND $ F$
2. $(Q+Z) < (N-M) $ AND $ (A+B) \le (S-X) $

as of the algorithm to convert i found the following to be the right conversion, but i could not find a way to check the if it's correct:

1. $ (A C - T >) (G H $ x $ B \le) OR (F) $ AND
2. $ (Q Z +) (N M -) < (A B +) (S X -) \le $ AND

is the solution i provided wrong and if yes what is the mistake i did?

Comment: More context is needed.  In particular, the conventions about precedence of operations.  With one convention, your answers are correct.  I thought the advantage of postfix notation was that parentheses are not needed: $$Q\; Z\; +\; N\; M\; -\; <\; A\; B\; +\; S\; X\; -\; \le\; \textbf{AND}$$

Comment: According to many sources, AND has higher priority than OR, which would change your answer to (1).  Also, in postfix notation you don't need any parentheses (you may want to separate items by spaces (or commas) so no confusion can result).